# Error after with compiling an existing program using JVCL HID device

Tags: delphi, jedi

I have just installed JEDI Library and VCL on Delphi 10.4.2.  When attempting to compile an existing working program which uses Jedi HIDCtrl I get the error...

```
[dcc32 Fatal Error] Hid.pas(896): F2051 Unit JvHidControllerClass was compiled with a different version of Hid.THIDDAttributes
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Try compiling your project with JEDI source files, not with precompiled DCUs

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I have the WINSOFT Native HID which I find is used in a trial form by the jvHIDControllerClass.  After removing the existing WINSOFT product it now compiles without error.